# How to make a mongo query to find all documents where an array contains a given id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I have a User collection which has a field "followingUsers" (array). This array contains the id's of other users. When an user gets deleted i want that every other user document no longer has a reference to the deleted user in their followUsers array. I am not experienced with mongo so i decided to make a find query first, but i get back an empty result on each attempt.

I wrote the following queries and none of them seem to work:

```
db.users.find({"followingUsers": "63d0522c655fa263cfe003e7"})
db.users.find({"followingUsers": {"$all": ["63d0522c655fa263cfe003e7"] } } )
```

In the image you can see the data i expect to get back: [Data i expect to get back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RytOA.png)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: One of the common errors is that you are storing ObjectIds while you are searching by strings. Either query by ObjectId or convert your schema to strings

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the user with nickname ray, i found the correct queries:

```
db.users.find( {'followingUsers': ObjectId("63cff74e3ae933124ee20d05")}  )
db.users.find( {'followingUsers': {"$all":[ ObjectId("63cff74e3ae933124ee20d05") ] }}  )
```

I was indeed storing ObjectId's inside the array and not just strings.